# Calculating inner product using Parsevals identity

Tags: proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Letting $x$ and $y$ be elements of some separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, we know that for any orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, we can write

$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i  \rangle e_i
$$

and similarly for $y$. Does it then follow that

$$
\langle x, y \rangle = \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i  \rangle e_i, \sum_{j=1}^\infty\langle y, e_j  \rangle e_j \right\rangle =  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i  \rangle  \langle y, e_j  \rangle \langle   e_i, e_j \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i  \rangle  \langle y, e_i  \rangle 
$$

I'm worried that bilinearity does not hold for infinite sums and I can't find a reference to this result anywhere, so I can't really tell if it is so trivial from Parseval, that noone bothers to mention it or if it is wrong.

Comment: This follows directly from continuity of the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is justified because the inner product is continuous. You can also get the result by noting  that, by Bessel's equality,  the map $\hat x:\mathcal H \to \ell^2(\mathbb N,\mathbb C):x\mapsto (\langle x,e_n\rangle)^{\infty}_{n=1} $ is an isometry, so an application of the polarization identity gives $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle \hat x,\hat y\rangle$ and the right hand side of this is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i  \rangle  \langle y, e_i  \rangle$ by definition of the inner product on $\ell^2(\mathbb N,\mathbb C).$